# Want bold text using * in html

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a textarea, a button and a div

```js
function showres() {
var text = document.getElementById('mytext');
var result = document.getElementById('resulthere');
result.innerHTML = text.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="mytxt" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="showres()">Click Me</button>
<div id="resulthere"></div>
```

It shows the value of textarea on the div on clicking the button
I want to show bold text on div if I input a string between two * in textarea
For example I type `Hello *Mike*` give Hello    **Mike** in div

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: see last line (edited)

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but have you tried to code something ?

Comment: @Striped should js replace method use here?

Comment: `text.replace('*', '<b>');` ?

Comment: This is a good start, test it and come back if you have an issue.

Comment: @Striped ,  but every scond `*` is end of <b> for every second therer should be replace `</b>` there not `<b>`... Thats the issue

Comment: Edit you post with your solution and a snippet of code we can test. CTRL-M shortcut when you are in the edit box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using Regex.

```js
function showres() {
  var text = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('resulthere');
  text.match(/\*([\w\s\d]+)?\*/g).forEach(function(match) {
    var str = match.substring(1, match.length - 1);
    text = text.replace(match, "<b>" + str + "</b>");
  });
  result.innerHTML = text;
}

document.getElementById('mytext').value = "this is *bold*";
showres();
```

```html
<textarea name="mytxt" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="showres()">Click Me</button>
<div id="resulthere"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to match bold pattern:

```
var yourString = 'something left *bold text 123*';
var regex = /\*([\w\s\d]+)?\*/g;
var matches = yourString.match(regex);
// matches = ['*bold text 123*']
```

Then you can use **replace** function to replace matched patern by your way!

```
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  yourString = yourString.replace(matches[i], yourBoldString);
}
```

Your can test your regex here https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the text starting and ending with `**` and then slice the `**` from the matching string. Following is my updated code -

```js
   function showres() {
    var text = document.getElementById('mytext');
    var result = document.getElementById('resulthere');
    var textVal = text.value
    var str = textVal.replace(/\*([\w\s\d]+)?\*/g, function(x){
     return "<b>"+x.slice(1, -1)+"</b>";
    });
    result.innerHTML = str;
   }
```

```html
<textarea name="mytxt" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="showres()">Click Me</button>
<div id="resulthere"></div>
```

Comment: This is better.